# In PyTorch, what exactly does the grad_fn attribute store and how is it used?

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

In PyTorch, the `Tensor` class has a `grad_fn` attribute. This *references* the operation used to obtain the tensor: for instance, if `a = b + 2`, `a.grad_fn` will be `AddBackward0`. But what does "reference" mean exactly?

Inspecting `AddBackward0` using `inspect.getmro(type(a.grad_fn))` will state that the only base class of `AddBackward0` is `object`. Additionally, the source code for this class (and in fact, any other class which might be encountered in `grad_fn`) is nowhere to be found in the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch)!

All of this leads me to the following questions:

1. What precisely is stored in `grad_fn` and how is it called during back-propagation?
2. How come the objects that get stored in `grad_fn` do not have some sort of common super class, and why is there no source code for them on GitHub?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`grad_fn` is a function "handle", giving access to the applicable gradient function.  The gradient at the given point is a coefficient for adjusting weights during back-propagation.

"Handle" is a general term for an object descriptor, designed to give appropriate access to the object.  For instance, when you open a file, `open` returns a file handle.  When you instantiate a class, the `__init__` function returns a handle to the created instance.  The handle contains references (usually memory addresses) to the data and functions for the item in question.

It appears as the generic `object` class because it's from the underlying implementation in another language, such that it does not map *exactly* to the Python `function` type.  PyTorch handles the inter-language call and return.  This hand-off is part of the pre-complied (shared-object) run-time system.

Is that enough to clarify what you see?

Comment: Pretty much, but where can I find more info on this "handle" business?

Comment: I updated with a generic description.  If that's not enough "more", then you'll need to research the specific type of handle you want.  If you're asking for how PyTorch implements access to the gradient function, you'll probably have to read some papers on its formation, or contact the PyTorch support team.

Comment: @Prune Do you have a practical example how one might use this `grad_fn` in a real use training context?  I came across this functionality as a surprise when I found out `torch.arange(1.0, 4.0, requires_grad=True)` and `torch.arange(3.0, requires_grad=True) + 1.0` do not return the same objects.  TIA.

Comment: @kfmfe04 This is a separate question; please post it as such.